# What is the "const operator" in C++?

Tags: c++

**Note:** This does not mean the const keyword, as the following example doesn't contain it at all.

[P1102R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1102r2.html) contains the following:

```
std::string s1 = "abc";
auto withParen = [s1 = std::move(s1)] () {
  std::cout << s1 << '\n'; 
};

std::string s2 = "abc";
auto noSean = [s2 = std::move(s2)] { // Note no syntax error.
  std::cout << s2 << '\n'; 
};
```

> These particular lambdas have ownership of the strings, so they ought to be able to mutate it, but s1 and s2 are const (because the `const` operator is declared `const` by default)...

What confuses me is the addition in brackets:

> because the `const` operator is declared `const` by default

What is the `const` operator in C++? How does this operator relate to the provided code example?

Comment: I think it means the `operator()`, i.e. the function-call operator.

Comment: You can add `mutable` after the `()` in your lambda. See [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) under "*specifiers*".

Comment: The subject of the entire paper is the `()` operator, and the author decided to save space by just saying "the operator" instead of "the `()` operator`" everywhere, since they assume you know which operator they're talking about: It's the operator in the title of the paper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referring to the fact that a lambda is really just a dressed up `operator()` overload in an anonymous class.

And, guess what? Lambda captures are merely members of the anonymous class.

The above example is equivalent to:

```
class [anonymous] {

    std::string s1;

public:

    [anonymous](std::string &&s1) : s1{ std::move(s1) } {}

    void operator()() const
    {
       std::cout << s1 << '\n'; 
    }
};

[anonymous] withParen{ std::move(s1) };
```

That's what the example lambda declaration boils down to (actual construction details hacked together merely to get the point across, there's only one move that takes place, in real-sies).

And note the `const` qualifier on the `operator()` overload. That's the `const` that the paper is referring to, in this particular instance.

That's why if the lambda tries to modify `s1` that results in a compilation failure.

Also note that using the `mutable` keyword is equivalent to ***not*** specifying a `const` qualifier on the `operator()` overload.